# R loop and download stock prices from yahoo.com

Tags: r, loops, download

I am trying to download stock prices from yahoo of several shares at once. I tried the following code, and it produces results but i would like the results to be presented in column per share.

So:

```
library(tseries)
library(zoo)

ticker<-c('AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG')

nShares<-length(ticker)

start<-'2015-01-01'

end<-'2015-09-01'

prices <- function() {

    y=get.hist.quote(instrument = ticker[i],
               start = start,
               end = end, quote = "AdjClose",
               retclass = "zoo")

   dimnames(y)[[2]] <- as.character(ticker[i])
   print (y)
  }  

for (i in 1:nShares){
  prices()
}
```

What I get as a result is a column with all time series of the 3 shares. I would like to have them all in 3 columns as:

```
Date              AAPL     MSFT    GOOG

2015-xx-xx      xx.xx    xx.xx   xx.xx
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying a bit your function:

```
prices <- function(ticker, start, end) {

  y=get.hist.quote(instrument = ticker,
                   start = start,
                   end = end, quote = "AdjClose",
                   retclass = "zoo")

  dimnames(y)[[2]] <- as.character(ticker)
  # print (y)
  y
}
```

You can achieve it in 1 line:

```
zoo_group <- do.call(cbind, lapply(tickers, prices, start=start, end=end))
head(zoo_group)
               AAPL     MSFT     GOOG
2015-01-02 107.9586 45.82758 524.8124
2015-01-05 104.9172 45.40616 513.8723
2015-01-06 104.9271 44.73971 501.9623
2015-01-07 106.3984 45.30815 501.1023
2015-01-08 110.4864 46.64103 502.6823
2015-01-09 110.6049 46.24900 496.1723
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the new package `tidyquant`, which makes getting stock prices for many stock symbols very simple:

```
library(tidyquant)

ticker <- c('AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG')

ticker %>%
    tq_get(get  = "stock.prices", 
           from = "2015-01-01",
           to   = "2015-09-01")
```